# Scrollbar failure with arguments

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, scrollbar

Another fun question for a usually simple task: a scrollbar. For starters, I'm aware that an Enter_Frame function needs to be placed in the startDragging function in order for the scrolling code to work. Trouble is, I can't get that far.

Here's the code:

```
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;


//establishes the size of the scroller knob
var contPERC = Math.round(text_mc.mask_mc.height / text_mc.content_mc.height * 100);
var knobHeight = contPERC;
scrollbar_mc.scroller_mc.height = knobHeight;
scrollbar_mc.scroller_mc.buttonMode = true;

//establishes the length of the scroll track bar
var trackHeight = scrollbar_mc.strip_mc.height;
var trackY = scrollbar_mc.scroller_mc.y;
var boundHeight = Math.round(trackHeight - knobHeight);
var boundsRect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0, boundHeight, 0, 0);

//adds the listeners
scrollbar_mc.scroller_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDragging);
scrollbar_mc.scroller_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDragging);
scrollbar_mc.scroller_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, stopDragging);


function startDragging(){
    scrollbar_mc.scroller_mc.startDrag(false, boundsRect);
    text_mc.content_mc.y = Math.round((scrollbar_mc.scroller_mc.y / 100) * text_mc.content_mc.height)
}

function stopDragging(){
    scrollbar_mc.scroller_mc.stopDrag();
}
```

but when I click on scroller_mc, I get this:

```
ArgumentError: Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on Scrollbar_fla::MainTimeline/startDragging(). Expected 0, got 1.
```

Answer (score 2):

Missing argument:

```
function startDragging(e:MouseEvent){ //<-
```

Same for your stopDraggin function.